# Uninstall IntelliJ Ultimate edition version 12

Tags: intellij

My evaluation licence has recently expired for IntelliJ Community edition version 12. I want to uninstall the application but do not have an option to in Ubuntu Software Centre.

I'm currently looking around my file system at what is installed as part of IntelliJ using a few [guides related to Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774315/in-intellij-on-os-x-how-do-you-clear-out-all-global-setting-info-licensing-etc). I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

<sub>*I genuinely thought I was using Ultimate edition when I posted this question. I subsequently bought a personal commercial licence. If your boss doesn't buy you a commercial one, getting a personal commercial one was worth it for me [as I like to contribute to what I use].</sub>

Comment: What happens when you search for IntelliJ in the Ubuntu Software Center and click anywhere on it? Normally an installed application would be highlighted in orange after you clicked on it, and there would be a **Remove** button on the right-hand side.

Comment: There is no evaluation version for the community edition, as it's an open source project. OP has probably installed the commercial IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To remove the product completely, do the following:

- Delete the installation directory
- Delete the "config" and "system" configuration directories. These contain IntelliJ IDEA's caches, configuration and plugins.

See http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181 for the OS specific locations of these two directories.

That should be all you need.

Answer (score 27):

First do `whereis idea` and it will tell you that you need to delete:

1. `/opt/idea-IC-173.4548.28/` This is where I installed IntelliJ.
2. `/usr/local/bin/idea` Only if you chose to install "Launcher Script" during IntelliJ installation.

Also need to delete:

3. `~/.IdeaIC2017.3`  It's a folder named after IntelliJ's version.
4. `$HOME/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-idea-ce.desktop` Only if you chose to install a main menu shortcut during installation.
5. In some cases you can also find jetbrains-idea.desktop under `/usr/share/applications/`

Comment: also 2019th idea stores some files here ```/home/username/.local/share```, ```/home/username/.java/.userPrefs```, ```/home/username/.gnome/apps```

Comment: Regarding point (3), IntelliJ IDEA 2020 is now using `~/.config/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2020.1`

Comment: is there a command like `whereis` for searching `IdeaIC***` ?

Comment: i found `/usr/share/applications/jetbrains-idea.desktop`

Answer (score 6):

If you happen to install the software using snap package manager, then it is as simple as

```
sudo snap remove intellij-idea-community
```

Answer (score 2):

On the desktop bar application, click the right mouse button and select "show details".
Then will open Ubuntu Software, if the Ubuntu knows the application installation should be "installed", so "remove" button should be enable, after that would be uninstalled.
As simple or more then windowns. Love for Linux