# I want to completely uninstall IntelliJ IDEA community Edition

Tags: uninstall, intellij

Installed in `Downloads\ideaIC-2018.2.3`  folder

Please write me **exact commands** (which I can copy paste) to remove it from the menu too.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/300692/817260

Comment: That isn't a linux-folder. How did you installed ideaIC?

Comment: using tar ball i guess

Comment: To write down an exact command would require us to know the directory which isn't just what you listed. Right click in the downloads folder when in your graphical file browser, select open terminal and then run: pwd and then post the output of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it by installing **JetBrains Toolbox** and uninstalling it from there

Comment: I recommend you to simply install IDEA community edition using snap store

Comment: sudo snap install intellij-idea-community --classic

Comment: if snap is not available run sudo apt install snapd its is tested and its easy to manage versions dependencies installing and removing.